# Result set in java returning columns in an order different from ms access table order

Tags: java

am using Ucanaccess JDBC driver for my application, at a moment it is able to connect to the ms access database but the columns are ordered differently, e.g in the database table "ID" column is second but it is return last. is there any one who has encountered the same problem?

Comment: If you need in the same order, extract data for a select query explicitly providing the order of rows in select statement like "select column1, column2, .... from ..."  , rather giving a "select * from ...".

Answer (score 0):

Use ColumnOrder=display connection paramenter, e.g.

jdbc:ucanaccess://c:/db/cico.mdb;COLUMNORDER=DISPLAY

Comment: thanks for your answer jamadei, i have tried it in my code and it has worked, but i have noticed that the program has became slower, is it that Ucanaccess is slower than JDBC ODBC or its something that can be fixed

Comment: It's usually it's slower in establishing the very first connection to a given database in the jvm life. Isolating this effect it may be faster, but there may be something you have to do with your code for specific kinds of transactions(e.g. massive updates).
It's  also possible drammatically improve the first connection time, but tunning depends on the  data size, content and structure.

Comment: @jamadei : Came very close to what you have told. But it is not working. Is it because the version is Access 2013. Is it because the version? Or I need to alter any thing. Your valuable suggestion would be of much help

Comment: Access 2013 is supported. You should better describe your issue in order to get our help. Do you get an exception? What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

How about writing out all columns in the order you want instead of using *. For example,

`select id, name, email from person;`

instead of

`select * from person;`